# How to use EOD as a array value

Tags: php, heredoc

How to use EOD , heredoc as a string array value?

```
class W
{
    const ERROR = [ 
    'en'=>'<<<EOD 
    error no: %s. 
    EOD'
    ];

    public function a(){
        $message = sprintf(self::ERROR['en'], '1');
        echo $message;
    }

}
$b = new W;
$b->a();
```

result in:

```
<<<EOD 
error no: 1. 
EOD
```

I need:

```
error no: 1.
```

Comment: You simply cannot do this.

Comment: @u_mulder I beg to differ.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  I meant you cannot do it with quotes, but I intended to answer something similar to yours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEREDOC doesn't take quotes.

```
    'en' => <<<EOD
error no: %s.
EOD
    ];
```

Note that there must be **no space** before the `EOD` marker, nor must there be anything after it.

If you want multiple array elements like this, you will need to put the comma separating the elements on a separate line.

```
    'en' => <<<EOD
error no: %s.
EOD
  , 'fr' => <<<EOD
erreur nº: %s.
EOD
    ]
```

Comment: so I can't use more than one array element?

Comment: You can. However, the comma separating elements will need to be on the line *after* the `EOD`.